# How to detect changes to a bound data

Tags: vb.net

Winforms App - VB.Net 4.6.1

I have a data table that I fill when my form loads as follows:

```
Private Sub OnFormLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     Me.ApGetMratesListTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsMRatesList.apGetMratesList)
End Sub
```

On the form I have textbox bound (Me.ApGetMratesListBindingSource) to a field in this datatable . I want to catch some sort of "RowChanged" event when the value in the textbox changes so I can set a "dirty" flag. Unfortunately after an hour of Googling and reading page after page with no examples of how to write the method I'm asking for help. Basically I cannot figure out how to refer to the event i.e. the part after HANDLES.

```
Private Sub SetDirty(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                     ByVal e As DataRowChangeEventArgs) Handles ?
        m_IsDirty = True
End Sub
```

I've experimented until I ran out of options. If anyone can clue me as to how to write the event for the above Sub I'd be very grateful. If the signature isn't correct please clue me on that as well. Thank you!

Comment: To use a [Handles Clause](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/handles-clause), the object (in your case a DataTable) must be declared using the [WithEvents Modifier](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/withevents). It appears you have added your DB objects via the designer.  Those objects cannot use the `Handles Clause`; so use a [AddHandler Statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement) to attach to the DataTable.RowChanged event.

Comment: Thank you TnTinMn. I've never actually done it manually before but I'll give it a go. I'm assuming I just have use AddHandler once when I load the form. Anyway thank you very much for your insight and I'm going to try this right now. :)

Comment: Use the example from [DataTable.RowChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.rowchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples) as a guide.  And yes, you can add the handler in the Form.Load event.  I suggest that you add the statement after filling the table.

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something as the event either isn't firing or I'm doing something wrong. I created a new method called AddHandlers  with one line:  AddHandler DsMRatesList.apGetMratesList.RowChanged, AddressOf SetDirty In the SetDirty method I set a breakpoint on the first line. I load up the app/form, change a value in a bound textbox, tab out, event doesn't seem to fire or I'm not catching it correctly. Sorry for the trouble. I call AddHandlers from mybase.load and it's after the fill.

Comment: Tracking the events can tricky.  The likely issue is that the bindingsource has not committed the changes back to the DataTable.  Add a button to your form and in its Click handler add the statement`Me.ApGetMratesListBindingSource.EndEdit()`.  This will commit the changes.  Make a change in the TextBox and click the button.  If you have a binding navigator, selecting a different record to also commit the changes.

Comment: You are the man... EndEdit worked. Not sure how it would work if I were using RowChanging instead of RowChanged but I'll take what I can get. If you want to throw a summary into an answer I'd be happy to mark it. Thank you TnTimMn for hooking me up!

Comment: I should have asked this earlier, but is the sole purpose of `m_IsDirty ` to determine at some later point if the DataTable has changed rows?  If so, that can be better handled by the [DataTable.GetChanges Method ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.getchanges?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Thank you TntinMn for the suggestion. I got that working as well and no adding of event handlers. Most appreciated.